# Is there any way we can add exif data to the jpeg in apache batik

Tags: java, dpi, batik

When we are converting svg to jpeg using apache batik with 300 dpi, there are no properties available for jpeg, Because of that, the image is open with default 72 dpi in every image viewer

Is there any way we can add exif data to the jpeg.